# Safari can't get correct keycode

Tags: javascript, safari

When I want to retrieve which key user pressed, it acts weird on Safari Mac OSX.

Since I'm not a native English speaker, so I switch my IME to Chinese input. Under such circumstance, when I press the top line of my keyboard(12345678...), the event.which always is 229. if I switch back to English input, when I press '2', event.which is 50.

This only happens with Safari, can anyone tell me how to get correct keyCode from event such as 'keydown' with Safari when the IME is activated?

Comment: there are several articles on this topic if you google.  I would reccommend using keyup instead of keydown , and I   http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html  ,  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html  , would also suggest alwasy checking for event.which or event.keyCode because different browsers behave differently

Comment: And this is only in Safari, you've tested other browsers, and they all work fine?

Comment: @adeneo I only tested with Safari and Chrome, Chrome works fine.